# What's wrong with this locales.yml file structure and how to fix it? (rails project)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, internationalization, locale, rails-i18n

Assuming that I have `views/admin/`, `views/user/`, `controller/admin/`, `controller/user/` (etc) folders, what's the right way to structure my `locales.yml` file so it works properly?

Right now, it looks like this:

```
en:
  views:
    admin:
      index:
        phrase1: Text1
        phrase2: Text2
        ... 
      new:
      show:
      ...
    user:
      index:
      new:
      show:
  controllers:
    ...
    etc
```

But when I put, say, `<%= t :phrase1 %>` in the `/views/admin/index.html.erb` code, it doesn't work (neither this nor `<%= t ".phrase1" %>` so it's not a syntax error). However, if I place `phrase1: Text1` just below the `en:` line (above any sub-dictionary), everything works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the key to get the translation. See it as a tree like structure. You have to tell the whole path to the final leaf.

In your case it is the following key:

```
"views.admin.index.phrase1"
```

For example we could have a translation file that looks like this:

```
en:
  home:
    salutation: "Welcome home"
  admin:
    salutation: "Welcome back master"
```

As you can see, we have two keys named salutation. If we used only "salutation" as key, it wouldn't be possible to tell which one we need.

Using the path `home.salutation` or `admin.salutation` makes it clear which text value we need.

Also, one reason why having to type the whole key is better than typing a part of it. Let say you are able to write a context dependent translation that will set a prefix to the key. When in controllers it adds: `controllers.` when in views `views.` and so on.

If you type the full key, you will always find where it is used in your project without problem.

If you start writing partial keys, like let say `dog`, you will find in the code every place where there is the word `dog` but not exactly `controllers.home.dog`. When it will be time to debug and change languages, you'll be quite happy to use a full key.

Comment: Ah, so I have to use the full keys all the time. Is there a configuration I can setup so Rails understands that when it is in `views/admin/index` it should just go to `locales.yml[:views][:admin][:index]`?

Comment: I don't remember there is a way to do that. Never really liked how translations are handled in rails. In case you're on a new project, you might want to do some research on using "gettext". I saw that: https://github.com/grosser/gettext_i18n_rails but I can't promise it works well.

Comment: If there was, you would make your code much more likely to go wrong, and harder to maintain, just to save you a bit of extra typing.  It's much better to be declarative and type the full path out.  After all, coders generally spend much more time debugging than they do typing out code in the first place.  Better to trade some typing for simplicity.

Comment: @MaxWilliams that's right, explicit is better than implicit. That's why I love gettext, can't be more explicit than that.